# Average score facing some technical issues

Tags: c

I have followed everything in the book, yet my average score fails me, every single time. I have debugged my program multiple times, in vain.

My minimal executable code:

```
#include <limits.h>

#include <stdbool.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>

#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TESTS 5
#define MAXQUESTION 10000

bool myread(const char * format, void * address) {
  char buffer[1024];
  fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
  return sscanf(buffer, format, address) == 1;
}

struct struc {
  int a;

  int b;

  int c;

  int add;

  int grade;
};

int sj(int n) {
  int t;

  t = rand() % n;

  return t;
}

void ctm_i(struct struc * t) {
  {
    t -> a = sj(101);
    t -> c = sj(4);
    if (t -> c == 1) {
      t -> b = sj(101 - (t -> a));
      t -> add = (t -> a) + (t -> b);
    } else {
      t -> b = sj((t -> a) + 1);
      t -> add = (t -> a) - (t -> b);
    }
    t -> grade = 0;
  }
}

void tcm_i(struct struc * t, int n) {
  int ad;

  printf(" ***********************************************************************"
    "*********\n");

  printf(" ......................................................................."
    ".........\n");

  printf(" Question %d\n\n", n + 1);

  printf(" You have 3 attempts for this question\n\n");

  if (t -> c == 1)
    printf(" %d+%d= ", t -> a, t -> b);
  else
    printf(" %d-%d= ", t -> a, t -> b);

  myread(" %d", & ad);
  if (ad == t -> add)

  {
    t -> grade = 10;

    printf(" You earned 10 marks\n\n");
  } else {
    printf("\n Incorrect, you have 2 attempts remaining\n\n");
    printf(" ");
    myread(" %d", & ad);

    if (ad == t -> add)

    {

      t -> grade = 7;

      printf(" You earned 7 marks\n\n");
    } else {
      printf("\n Incorrect, you have 1 attempt remaining\n\n");
      printf(" ");
      myread(" %d", & ad);

      if (ad == t -> add)

      {

        t -> grade = 5;

        printf(" You earned 5 marks\n\n");
      } else {
        t -> grade = 0;

        printf("\n Failure, 0 mark\n\n");

        printf("\n The correct answer is %d\n\n", t -> add);
      }
    }
  }

  printf(" ......................................................................."
    ".........\n");

  printf(" ***********************************************************************"
    "*********\n");
}

void quiz(char name[]) {
  int rounds = 0;
  int highest = 0;
  int lowest = INT_MAX;
  float allScore = 0;
  float avg = 0.0;

  int i, j, g = 0;
  struct struc test[MAX_TESTS];

  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

  for (;;) {
    rounds++;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++) // generate all questions
    {
      ctm_i( & test[i]);

      for (j = 0; j < i; j++)

        if (test[i].a == test[j].a && test[i].b == test[j].b && test[i].c == test[j].c)
          //if question is already present
          ctm_i( & test[i]); //then re-generate
    }
    printf("\n Are you ready? Press Enter key to continue. ");
    myread("", NULL);

    for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      printf(" *******************************************************************"
        "**"
        "***********\n");

      printf(" ..................................................................."
        ".."
        "...........\n");
    }

    // Take quiz
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++)
      tcm_i( & test[i], i);

    printf(" End\n\n");

    bool done = false;
    bool unsure = true;
    bool showS = true;

    while (unsure) {
      unsure = false;
      puts("\n");
      if (showS) {
        puts(" Enter 'S' to show results");
      }
      puts(" Enter 'P' to play another round");
      puts(" Enter 'R' to return to main menu");
      char choice;
      printf(" ");
      myread(" %c", & choice);
      printf("\n");
      if (choice == 'r' || choice == 'R') {
        done = true;
      } else {

        ///////////////////////// Changes    /////////////

        g = 0;
        // calculate total score for current round
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++) {
          g += test[i].grade; //add score of each question
        }
        allScore += g; //add current round's score to total
        avg = allScore / rounds; //average of all rounds

        if (g > highest) {
          highest = g;
        }

        if (g < lowest) {
          lowest = g;
        }

        if (choice == 'S' || choice == 's') {
          showS = false;
          if (rounds == 1) {
            printf(" Final score: %d/100\n", g); //display round score
            printf(" ****** Player: %s ******\n", name);
          } else {
            printf(" Round %d score: %d/100\n", rounds, g); //display round score
            printf(" Highest score: %d/100\n", highest);
            printf(" Lowest score : %d/100\n", lowest);
            printf(" Average score: %f/100\n", avg);
            printf(" ****** Player: %s ******\n", name);
          }
          unsure = true;
        } else if (choice == 'P' || choice == 'p') {
          /// nothing to be done here
          //we will display next test
        } else {
          puts(" Invalid input!");
          unsure = true;
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////

      }
    }
    if (done)
      break;
  }
}

int main() {
  char i1 = '1';
  char name[25]; // ig;
  printf("\n Welcome");

  printf("\n");
  while (i1 != 0) {

    printf("\n");
    //printf(" **********************Welcome %s! *********************\n", name);
    printf(" ************************ Main Menu of Maths Quiz ***************************\n");
    printf(" * 1.Enter Quiz                                                             *\n");
    printf(" * 2.Quit                                                                   *\n");
    printf(" ****************************************************************************\n");
    printf(" Please choose one from 1-2:\n");
    printf(" ");
    myread(" %c", & i1);
    switch (i1) {
    case '1':
      printf("\n Enter Quiz:\n");
      quiz(name); // calling quiz function defined in file "maincode.c"
      break;
    case '2':
      printf(" Quit.\n\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Hope that fulfilled the definition of an MRE.
So I have snipped off some bombastic lines, and the ones left are the important ones, I think.

Comment: Post a *complete* example.  You don't include the source for `myread()` or `ctm_i()`

Comment: A complete example? Do you mean the complete code?????

Comment: @TheNovice no, not the complete code but a [mcve]. This means some work for you, but you might even find the problem yourself in the process

Comment: If you can't solve the problem with the complete code, why do you expect others to solve it with only a portion of the code?  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is `myread("%c", &choice);` the tip of an unshown input problem? Typically we would add a space in this `scanf` format specifier, like `" %c"` to eat up the newline left in the input buffer.

Comment: Umm, there is no minimal reproducible example I think, my code is interlinked.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you for the tip! I guess that's where my problem lies!

Comment: Sorry, I have typed in the scores incorrectly.

Comment: Please, please, only **copy/paste** from actual code, and input and output data.

Comment: There is always a MRE, @TheNovice, but constructing one sometimes requires more work.  Read the link you were previously provided: constructing a MRE often requires more work than just cutting out select portions of your code.  It is, moreover, a very useful skill to have, as it is a powerful debugging technique in its own right.

Comment: Okay, I think I really need to create an MRE right now, as the average score is still wrong for games played 3 rounds or above.

Comment: Okay, guys, my minimal executable code is now on board!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your function `quiz`, and in particular in the `while (unsure)` loop. In this loop, you add the most recent score to the running total:

```
allScore += g; //add current round's score to total
```

This should happen once per round played. But if the user inputs "S" or something invalid, your program sets

```
unsure = true;
```

which means the loop will run again, before the next round is played. It then adds the most recent score a second time to the grand total.

The most logical solution would be to move all the calculations of totals, maximum, minimum, average out of the while-loop. The loop serves a different purpose: it is for user interaction and reporting, not for processing results.

Answer (score 0):

possible chance of multiple avg calculation for same round again. Keep flag to track accounting of score, so we will not do the same more than once till the game is not played again.

```
    #include <limits.h>

    #include <stdbool.h>

    #include <stdio.h>

    #include <stdlib.h>

    #include <time.h>

    #include <string.h>

    #define MAX_TESTS 5
    #define MAXQUESTION 10000

    bool myread(const char * format, void * address) {
      char buffer[1024];
      fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
      return sscanf(buffer, format, address) == 1;
    }

    struct struc {
      int a;

      int b;

      int c;

      int add;

      int grade;
    };

    int sj(int n) {
      int t;

      t = rand() % n;

      return t;
    }
    void ctm_i(struct struc * t) {
      {
        t -> a = sj(101);
        t -> c = sj(4);
        if (t -> c == 1) {
          t -> b = sj(101 - (t -> a));
          t -> add = (t -> a) + (t -> b);
        } else {
          t -> b = sj((t -> a) + 1);
          t -> add = (t -> a) - (t -> b);
        }
        t -> grade = 0;
      }
    }

    void tcm_i(struct struc * t, int n) {
      int ad;

      printf(" ***********************************************************************"
"*********\n");
      printf(" ......................................................................."
".........\n");

      printf(" Question %d\n\n", n + 1);

      printf(" You have 3 attempts for this question\n\n");

      if (t -> c == 1)
        printf(" %d+%d= ", t -> a, t -> b);
      else
        printf(" %d-%d= ", t -> a, t -> b);

      myread(" %d", & ad);
      if (ad == t -> add)

      {
        t -> grade = 10;

        printf(" You earned 10 marks\n\n");
      } else {
        printf("\n Incorrect, you have 2 attempts remaining\n\n");
        printf(" ");
        myread(" %d", & ad);

        if (ad == t -> add)

        {

          t -> grade = 7;

          printf(" You earned 7 marks\n\n");
        } else {
          printf("\n Incorrect, you have 1 attempt remaining\n\n");
          printf(" ");
          myread(" %d", & ad);

          if (ad == t -> add)

          {

            t -> grade = 5;

            printf(" You earned 5 marks\n\n");
          } else {
            t -> grade = 0;

            printf("\n Failure, 0 mark\n\n");

            printf("\n The correct answer is %d\n\n", t -> add);
          }
        }
      }

      printf(" ......................................................................."
".........\n");

      printf(" ***********************************************************************"
"*********\n");
    }

    void quiz(char name[]) {
      int rounds = 0;
      int highest = 0;
      int lowest = INT_MAX;
      float allScore = 0;
      float avg = 0.0;

      int i, j, g = 0;
      struct struc test[MAX_TESTS];

      srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

      for (;;) {
        rounds++;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++) // generate all questions
        {
          ctm_i( & test[i]);

          for (j = 0; j < i; j++)

            if (test[i].a == test[j].a && test[i].b == test[j].b && test[i].c == test[j].c)
              //if question is already present
              ctm_i( & test[i]); //then re-generate
        }
        printf("\n Are you ready? Press Enter key to continue. ");
        myread("", NULL);

        for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
          printf(" *******************************************************************"
    "**"
    "***********\n");

          printf(" ..................................................................."
    ".."
    "...........\n");
        }

        // Take quiz
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++)
          tcm_i( & test[i], i);

        printf(" End\n\n");

        bool done = false;
        bool unsure = true;
        bool showS = true;
        bool acct = false;

while (unsure) {
  unsure = false;
  puts("\n");
  if (showS) {
    puts(" Enter 'S' to show results");
  }
  puts(" Enter 'P' to play another round");
  puts(" Enter 'R' to return to main menu");
  char choice;
  printf(" ");
  myread(" %c", & choice);
  printf("\n");
  if (choice == 'r' || choice == 'R') {
    done = true;
  } else {

    ///////////////////////// Changes    /////////////
    if (false == acct) {
    g = 0;
    // calculate total score for current round
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_TESTS; i++) {
      g += test[i].grade; //add score of each question
    }
    allScore += g; //add current round's score to total
    avg = allScore / rounds; //average of all rounds

    if (g > highest) {
      highest = g;
    }

    if (g < lowest) {
      lowest = g;
    }
    acct = true;
    }
    if (showS &&(choice == 'S' || choice == 's')) {
      showS = false;
      if (rounds == 1) {
        printf(" Final score: %d/100\n", g); //display round score
        printf(" ****** Player: %s ******\n", name);
      } else {
        printf(" Round %d score: %d/100\n", rounds, g); //display round score
        printf(" Highest score: %d/100\n", highest);
        printf(" Lowest score : %d/100\n", lowest);
        printf(" Average score: %f/100\n", avg);
        printf(" ****** Player: %s ******\n", name);
      }
      unsure = true;
    } else if (choice == 'P' || choice == 'p') {
      /// nothing to be done here
      //we will display next test
    } else {
      puts(" Invalid input!");
      unsure = true;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////

  }
}
if (done)
  break;
      }
    }

    int main() {
      char i1 = '1';
      char name[25]; // ig;
      printf("\n Welcome");

      printf("\n");
      while (i1 != 0) {

printf("\n");
//printf(" **********************Welcome %s! *********************\n", name);
printf(" ************************ Main Menu of Maths Quiz ***************************\n");
printf(" * 1.Enter Quiz                                                             *\n");
printf(" * 2.Quit                                                                   *\n");
printf(" ****************************************************************************\n");
printf(" Please choose one from 1-2:\n");
printf(" ");
myread(" %c", & i1);
switch (i1) {
case '1':
          printf("\n Enter Quiz:\n");
          quiz(name); // calling quiz function defined in file "maincode.c"
          break;
        case '2':
          printf(" Quit.\n\n");
        }
      }
      return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
     Enter 'S' to show results
      Enter 'P' to play another round
      Enter 'R' to return to main menu
      s

      Round 2 score: 47/100
      Highest score: 50/100
      Lowest score : 47/100
      Average score: 48.500000/100
      ****** Player:  ******
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get a ````Non-object type 'int (const char *)' is not assignable```` warning for the line ````acct=true````. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Is it possible to share complete code and the command used to compiled. not seeing any warning with cc <file> or "cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors avg3.c". t

Comment: Sure! Here is the link to my complete code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NW7qfcRQGS/, I would be extremely grateful if you can help resolve this ````average score```` fiasco that has been going on for over a week now. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I am using Xcode v12.2 as my IDE.

Comment: shared code is getting compiled for me, not seeing the flag "acct" in code. I have added the flag and compiled, not seeing any warning related to the flag.  
 compilation didnt give any error. There are already bool used in the code, and we are adding a new bool that should not be causing any issue, only issue could be missing brackets or ";".  result :

Comment: 1) added flag at line 265 , 
265         bool acct_checked = false;  
2) added check on line "287" before processing score , 
286          if (acct_checked == false) {
3) chnaging flag to true after processing score on line "306" and closing bracket on 307, 
306                 acct_checked = true;

Comment: Can you please send me the full code that you have corrected?